# Python traitlet configuration

Tags: python, jupyter, python-traitlets

I have a need to load a traitlet configuration for a Jupyter client from S3. The notebook client will not have access to the file system to locate it there. Is there already a way to do this? If not, is there any documentation on how to provide an alternate file loader for the configuration file?